# findIndex not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, gulp

I would like to ask which GULP PLUGIN can I use to recompile js code so it works on IE. At the moment I'm trying to use **findIndex** but it can't recognize this array method:

```
function qualifiesForPension(element) {
  return element >= 60;
}

[12, 75, 8, 90, 44].findIndex(qualifiesForPension);
```

Comment: use polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked....